# mvc3 c# streamreader file not reading

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a file, which the users browse and hit the upload button, i save the file on the server, appdata/uploads in the application directory. then i try to read it using stream reader and then parse it. on my local development enviornment it works fine, but when i deploy it on a server it does not work at all. any suggestions?? thank you

```
//Save LoadList File:
            DateTime uploadDate = DateTime.Now;
            string destinationPath = string.Format("{0}\\{1}\\{2}\\{3}\\", Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), uploadDate.ToString("yyyy"), uploadDate.ToString("MMM"), uploadDate.ToString("dd"));
              if (!Directory.Exists(destinationPath))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(destinationPath);

              string storedFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}.json", destinationPath, System.Guid.NewGuid());
                file.ElementAt(0).SaveAs(storedFileName);

           //FileImport is a static class
          var Pair = FileImport.CyclesCompleted(storedFileName);





           private static string LoadTextFromFile(string fileName)
                {
                    StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(fileName);
                    string text = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    streamReader.Close();
                    return text;
                }
```

Comment: I'm presuming that the file is placed in an folder that the IIS user has permissions to access? Without seeing too much, this could be a security issue.

Comment: well im changing my approach now, im going to read the file before saving it but doing something like this [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.inputstream.aspx.  I just want to see how to send the string to a streamreader. Because in other parts of my code im using a streamreader to parse my file content. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving file on server ususlly results in permission errors since most accounts can't write to default location on server. You may get away with using [Path.GetTempFileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettempfilename.aspx), but even in this case some accounts (i.e. account that requests run for "anonymous user") will not have permissions to read/write to that location.

If you simply need to parse uploaded file you can copy stream to MemoryStream and create StreamReader over this memory stream. You may be able to use Stream for uploaded file directly, but it will not support seaking (may work as you are using StreamReader which does not seek).

Comment: well the stream reader does not read posted files on server, the file has to be saved first. so instead of saving the file i amusing the httppostedfile.input stream to read a json file but the resulting string looks like in bytes. any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure why you can't create reader over HttpPostedFile.InputStream. Check out this constructor of [StreamReader(stream, encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143456.aspx) that should also help with encoding issues.